# Laravel 10 "Credentials must be an instance of 'Aws\Credentials\CredentialsInterface" Error calling Lambda (but all other AWS services fine)

Tags: php, laravel, aws-lambda, aws-php-sdk

I have a Laravel 10 application which heavily uses AWS services including SES, SNS, SQS, Lamda, Aurora and S3.
Today, for no reason I can determine, calls to Lambda functions from the application started failing with an error:

**Credentials must be an instance of 'Aws\Credentials\CredentialsInterface, an associative array that contains "key", "secret", and an optional "token" key-value pairs, a credentials provider function, or false.**

All other AWS functions are working fine so this would imply there is no problem with the key/secret (stored in the .env file).

I though this might be a permission issue (with the function not being cable to access .env or a config file) so I've reset all the file/folder permissions on the entire project.  No dice.

I simply have no idea where to start on this, little to no information out there about the error.

I should also mention, the Lambda's run fine when executed directly from the AWS console with the same value passed to them.

Thing I've tried:

- Hardcoding the credentials
- Various options from the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/guide/credentials.html), such as:
- Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider::env
- Creating a Credentials object (new Credentials(env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'));)

Any ideas?

Calls are made in various places, all failing with the same error.  An example of one is:

```
        $client = LambdaClient::factory(array('version' => "latest", 'credentials' => array('key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), 'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')), 'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'eu-west-1')));
        $response = $client->invoke([
            'FunctionName' => 'org_DataPull',
            'InvocationType' => 'RequestResponse',
            'Payload' => '{"organisation_id":"'.$organisation_id.'"}',
        ]);
```

And it gets weirder, after completely redeploying my application, including the vendor folder, permissions, etc. I was able to get this working in script I directly execute using this:

```
    $credentials = new Credentials(env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'));
    $client = new LambdaClient(['version' => "latest", 'credentials' => $credentials, 'region' => 'eu-west-1']);
    $response = $client->invoke([
        'FunctionName' => 'org_DataPull',
        'InvocationType' => 'RequestResponse',
        'Payload' => '{"organisation_id":"'.$organisation_id.'"}',
    ]);
```

However . . .

When I use the exact same code in the Laravel job where this has been running fine for months, I get an error three times (because the job retries twice) but the errors seems to randonly be either:

*Credentials must be an instance of 'Aws\Credentials\CredentialsInterface, an associative array that contains "key", "secret", and an optional "token" key-value pairs, a credentials provider function, or false.*

OR

*The security token included in the request is invalid.
UnrecognizedClientException (client): The security token included in the request is invalid.*

All I can think is that for some reason, the Laravel job is having trouble access the .env file or similar (though I'd expect a related error).

The problem gets even weirder . . .
One of my lambda calls is working fine (from a job and directly), there is no different in the code other than the Lambda function name.  All functions word when called directly so I'm still at a loss.  I'll keep posting updates as I diagnose in case it helps someone else.  Modified dates on the Lamda function confirm none of them has been altered in months.

Comment: Which PHP SDK version are you using?

Comment: aws/aws-crt-php v1.2.1
aws/aws-sdk-php 3.276.2
aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel 3.8.1

Comment: @ArpitJain, I've also updated my question to include the latest 'drama'!  :-)

Comment: In version 3 of the AWS SDK for PHP, the way you instantiate a client has changed. Instead of the factory methods in version 2, you simply instantiate a client by using the new keyword.

Comment: Thanks @ArpitJain, both methods should (and do) work, I'm having the same issue whether I used the new constructor or the old factory method,

Comment: i think there were error in get the env parmas so can you please try with your old code and old lambda but using this laravel command before call lambda : php artisan config:clear

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't conclusive, I wanted to post what I did in case it helps others.

Out of sheer frustration, I recreated the Laravel Job which invoked the Lambda function and recreated the Lambda function too.  Both with identical code in all but one respect, the job name and the lambda function name both contained an underscore.  In the new versions I removed the underscore - I doubt that was the issue since it worked fine for months.